# delete selected row data from database

Tags: c#

I have been working on this code for hours now it shows the messagebox that the information has been successfully deleted but it does not delete on the database I can't seem to find where I went wrong.

```
 private void simpleButton5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
          DataGridViewRow delrow = dataGridView1.Rows[i];
          if (delrow.Selected == true)
          {
                //A YesNo enabled messagebox
                DialogResult dialogResult = DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraMessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want delete the selected client's information?", " ", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                //An if statement for a yes selected button on the messagebox
                if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
                    try
                    {
                        Conn.Open();
                        SqlCommand Scd = new SqlCommand("Delete From Client WHERE ClientID=" + i + "" ,Conn);
                        Scd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        Conn.Close(); 
                        DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraMessageBox.Show("You have successfully deleted the selected client's information on the system", " ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraMessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                    }
                  }
                //An if statement for a no selected button on the messagebox
                else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
                {
                    //Closing this form and opening the main menu form
                    this.Hide();
                    MainMenu mm = new MainMenu();
                    mm.ShowDialog();
                    this.Close();
                    this.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
     }
```

Comment: You have conflated the VIEW of the data your provide the user with the actual data.  A DataAdapter would allow you to get rid of all that code: `myDA.Update(myDT);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ClientID` is problably not `i` (this is just the row index). Get the real client id from the row data.

```
int clientID = (int)dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[indexOfClientIDColumn].Value;
SqlCommand Scd =
    new SqlCommand("Delete From Client WHERE ClientID=" + clientID , Conn);
```

or get the right column by name

```
int clientID = (int)dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["ClientID"].Value;
```

And also better use [command parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Answer (score 5):

```
"Delete From Client WHERE ClientID=" + i + ""
```

You are deleting a row with ClientID = `i`. But wait whats `i`? its the temp variable inside your for loop. So unless the your data grid view contains all rows in the DB, and the ID starts with 1, and the ID are incremented by 1 each time you will be deleting some other client's data.

You will likely to be doing something like `WHERE ClientID=" + delrow["ClientID"]` or any other way which you can obtain the actual ID.

But as a side note. Do yourself a favor and use [Parameterized Sql](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738521(v=vs.100).aspx) to prevent sql injection.

Answer (score 2):

According to your loop, your variable i is RowIndex and it's always going to be 0, 1, 2, 3, 4... n

IMO, I don't think you got the ClientID with those values in your Client table.  Could you double check whether you have the same key value as those.

You need to get the ClientID back from your "DataGridViewRow"

Answer (score 2):

I believe the error is here:

`SqlCommand Scd = new SqlCommand("Delete From Client WHERE ClientID=" + i + "" ,Conn);`

You are passing as ClientID the line of the datagrid, instead of the real ID.

Comment: Ok i understand, any suggestion as to how I can actually fix the code